# How to load arbitrarily select JARs for a classloader?

Tags: java

I would like to be able to load different versions of a JAR file, representing a client API, based on the version of the server I'm talking to. Unfortunately, each version of the server requires a different client API. Is there a way to create a ClassLoader that find class files based on a specified CLASSPATH? In other words, I want to tell the ClassLoader the sequence of locations for searching class files.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like a custom ClassLoader that looks in different locations based upon some configuration. For example, in one case it may looked in /foo, another in /bar, and in yet another it may look in /foo first and then /bar. If that's correct, it isn't that tough, actually. Check out URLClassLoader (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). You can specify to the ClassLoader which URLs (which can be local directories or files) and "The URLs will be searched in the order specified for classes and resources after first searching in the specified parent class loader."

The key is that the parent ClassLoader can't know about the paths that you don't want searched, so you'll have to do some of the class path configuration manually instead of allowing the JVM to take care of it.